# Cannot get a mail from magento on gmail

Tags: magento-1.9

I am still building my onlineshop now.I found an issue that cannot get a mail like when ordering,registered id and so from magento on Gmail.
Although I could get a mail my private domain,cannot on my Gmail.

I just installed and set-up the extension which is SMTP Pro,but it does not work on it.Do you know how to send a mail to Gmail account?
I no longer have idea.That would be great if you give a tip or something helpful source.

Comment: Please check spam folder in your gmail account

Comment: I have already checked it,but does not exist..

Answer (score 0):

Update your website email address in each & every email fields of admin panel. Then you can receive the emails.

Comment: Yes,I have already set my email account.

Comment: use https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=AOE+Scheduler&pl=0

Comment: use this extension & set the cron jobs on your cpanel

Comment: Okzz no problem

Comment: So AOE Scheduler does not help?

Comment: It works for me, after installing AOE scheduler you have to set the CRON JOB

Comment: First,does it work?
SMTP host:sv***.xserver.jp/SMTP PORT:587/SMTP user:shop@******.co.jp/SMTP pass:••••••••(key of email)
I cannot use SMTP at all

Comment: And should I not change cron jobs on cpanel if I use that extension?